# Integrating $ \frac{\mathrm{d}^{2}v}{\mathrm{d}y^{2}} = \frac{\mathrm{d}p}{\mathrm{d}x} $

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

How would I go about integrating this to figure out what $\mathrm{d}v/\mathrm{d}y$ is? The bounds on $y$ is ($H$--> constant upper, and $y$ varied lower). I know how to generally do it but I'm not sure how to formally write it out.

Comment: Is there anything special about $\frac{dp}{dx}$ and how it otherwise relates to $v$ and $y$?

Comment: @Element118 no it is independent of y. If you like, replace it with a constant G.

Comment: @Element118 if you were curious $\frac{dp}{dx}$ relates to a pressure gradient in the x direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We integrate both sides with respect to $y$:

$\int_y^H\frac{d^2v}{d^2y}dy=\int_y^H\frac{dp}{dx}dy$

$\left.\frac{dv}{dy}\right|_{y=H}-\frac{dv}{dy}=(H-y)\frac{dp}{dx}$

We integrate both sides with respect to $y$ again:

$\int_y^H\left(\left.\frac{dv}{dy}\right|_{y=H}-\frac{dv}{dy}\right)dy=\int_y^H(H-y)\frac{dp}{dx}dy$

$(H-y)\left.\frac{dv}{dy}\right|_{y=H}-\left.v\right|_{y=H}+v=\frac{dp}{dx}\left(\frac{y^2+H^2}{2}-yH\right)$